# How to create a new document from a Document Template using Client Object Model

Tags: document-library, client-object-model, silverlight, document-template

I require to programatically create a new document using the Document Template URL of the document Library and this requires to be done using the Client Object Model. I also require to do this without using workflow.

Could someone advise on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<script>

  function createDocument()
  {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var docLib = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Docs");

    var rootFolder = docLib.get_rootFolder();
    clientContext.load(rootFolder);

    var files = rootFolder.get_files();
    clientContext.load(files);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
      function()
      {
        files.addTemplateFile(rootFolder.get_serverRelativeUrl() + "/foo.docx", 0);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync();
      }, 

      function(sender, args){alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());}
    );
  }    
</script>

<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="createDocument()">Create Document</a></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Matthias , I've just tried to implement your code, it creates the document but it is somehow damaged, It doesn't open. I am using a custom content type with custom document template. Do I have to specify any other properties in this case? any ideas? Thanks!